# Converting http request into https request in Spring 3 application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application works on http request. I wanted to change that to https. 
I am using Spring 3 framework and Tomcat 7 Server. 
I don't know from where to start or how to do this.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Tomcat setting. You need to replace your HTTP Connector with an HTTPS Connector. This requires a bit of setting up but it's all described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).